# Update selected column in SQLite table in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to updated selected columns in my database, however i am unable to get the updated data.As soon as the user click on next button, the data should get updated.There are total 12 fields that needs to be updated in the table.

The scenario is bit different, I already have one activity where primarily say if 5 fields are getting inserted, and in 2nd activity I need to UPDATE 5 fields in the SAME TABLE

Thanks in advance

Note: dba is DBAdapter i.e the database and myDB is SQLiteDatabase

```
 nxt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_nxt);
          nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String b1=t1.getText().toString();
                String b2=goal_website_trying_to_achieve_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b3=communicate_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b4=success_look_like_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b5=usp_insights_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b6=act_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b7=market_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b8=your_current_website_www_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b9=your_current_website_good_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b10=your_current_website_bad_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b11=your_current_website_type_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b12=your_current_website_update_edttxt.getText().toString();
                String b13=your_current_website_supporting_edttxt.getText().toString();

                if(!validatescreen2()){
                    return;
                }

                else{

                    myDB = DBAdapter.openDatabase(Newform_Screen2.this,DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE);




                    String updatequery = "UPDATE"+ DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE+ " SET ";       

                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_1 = '" + b1 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_2 = '" + b2 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_3 = '" + b3 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_4 = '" + b4 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_5 = '" + b5 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_MESSAGE_6 = '" + b6 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1 = '" + b7 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2 = '" + b8 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3 = '" + b9 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE = '" + b10 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED = '" + b11 + "',";
                    updatequery = updatequery + " KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER = '" + b12 + ",";

                    updatequery = updatequery +  "WHERE" + DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "=" + mRowId +"';";

                    try{
                        myDB.execSQL(updatequery);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        //Log("Caught while writing response" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }finally{
                        if(myDB != null)myDB.close();
                        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    }

                }
            }
          });
```

and in `DBAdapter` class

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(Context context, String DBname){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    myDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DBname,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor rs = null;
    boolean tableExists;
    try{
        rs = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE 1=0", null );
        tableExists = true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        tableExists = false;
    }finally{
        if (rs != null) rs.close();
    }
    if(!tableExists) {
        myDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    return myDB;
}

public static void executeQuery(SQLiteDatabase db,String query){

    if(db != null){
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

}

public static Cursor selectQuery(SQLiteDatabase db,String query){

    if(db != null)
    {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return c;
    }
    else
    return null;

}

public static void closeDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db){
    if (db != null)
    {
        //Log("Closing Database conn");
        db.close();
    }
}
```

after making changes, but still unable to update..do I need to make any other change??

```
dba.open();
                        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_1, b2);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_2, b3);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_3, b4);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_4, b5);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_5, b6);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_6, b7);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1, b8);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2, b9);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3, b10);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE, b11);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED, b12);
                        args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER, b13);

                        String where = "_id = " + mRowId.toString();

                myDB.update(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE, args,where, null);    
                            dba.close();
                            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    }


                }

              });
```

after adding try/catch

```
try{
                        myDB.beginTransaction();
                dba.open();
                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_1, b2);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_2, b3);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_3, b4);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_4, b5);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_5, b6);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE_6, b7);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_1, b8);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_2, b9);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_3, b10);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_TYPE, b11);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_NEED, b12);
                args.put(DBAdapter.KEY_YOUR_CURRENT_WEBSITE_OTHER, b13);

                String where =DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID +"=" + mRowId.toString();


                myDB.update(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE, args,where, null);
                myDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    dba.close();

                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     finally {
                        myDB.endTransaction();
                       }
                }


            }

          });
```

now i am getting this error

```
01-29 17:52:38.874: W/System.err(9257): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 17:52:38.874: W/System.err(9257):     at com.example.sales.Newform_Screen2$3.onClick(Newform_Screen2.java:150)
01-29 17:52:38.874: W/System.err(9257):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-29 17:52:38.883: W/System.err(9257):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-29 17:52:38.883: W/System.err(9257):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-29 17:52:38.883: W/System.err(9257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-29 17:52:38.893: W/System.err(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Comment: don't use execSQL. that's, like, the first line of the sqlite documentation on android ?

Comment: (for one, you have no way of knowing your update data are properly escaped with your method)

Comment: @njzk2 : plz suggest what should be used

Comment: i don't suggest anything. android does. "you're encouraged to use (...) update" that's a method from SQLiteDatabase. (ps : the issue you are facing is quite trivial, you'll find where it is by reading your code again and again. but using 'update', you wouldn't have to. Also, reading, and posting, the stacktrace would help you)

Comment: @android2013 : The scenario is bit different, I already have one activity where primarily say if 5 fields are getting inserted, and in 2nd activity I need to UPDATE 5 fields in the SAME TABLE

Comment: no, android2013 answer is correct. You'll avoid typos in writing your query (which is the reason your query currently fails, btw)

Comment: So according to you, I should update rest of the values in the Activity-2 ?? using [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update)

Comment: i don't have the code for your whole activities, and your question is not very clear, but you have a typo in your query (plus security flaws), which you wouldn't have if you used `update()`

Answer (score 0):

Use update method instead of query like `myDB.update(mTableName, values, sWhereClause, null);` values is ContentValues object, put all your fields and values in this object ,sWhereClause is where clause without where word on selected fields like name='xyz'

Comment: please have a look at above made changes..but still unable to update

Comment: Please put a try catch around update  and print error message in console.

Comment: most probably your mRowId is wrong , update will return a value ( number of rows updated ) print them if you see any update count.

Answer (score 0):

Use update method.

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Convenience method for updating rows in the database.
You can get more information from 
-
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update

Comment: please have a look at above made changes..but still unable to update

Comment: Try this    'String where = DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID +"= ?" ;
                   String whereArgs[] = new String [] {mRowId.toString()};
                   myDB.update(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE,     args,where,whereArgs);'

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are doing a lot of mistakes in your SQLite-Statement. First of all, the last "," should be deleted, before you write "WHERE". Second, there should be Spaces before and after "WHERE". And last but not least, you need a ";" IN YOUR SQLite-Query-String AT THE END OF THE STRING. Well these 3 things might not fully fix the problem, but they should at least make you get closer to the solution.